# Dynamically populate string literally templates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I select a person from the list it grabs the id of a name and stores it an array with map.

I then have a string literal which gets populated with the ID.

```
  const id = value.map(person => person.value)

   console.log('from',id)
```

current output:

```
[u29219]
```

withe the results looking like this:

```
const results = await verifiedGet(`get_user/?$u29219?admin_form=True`, user.user)
```

and then if I add another person the array would look like this

```
[u29219, u302932]
```

results:

```
const results = await verifiedGet(`get_user/hello?$u29219,u302932?admin_form=True`, user.user)
```

When a user is added to the array I want to be able to iterate through the results with the ID only populating once if a user is selected twice

```
const results = await verifiedGet(`get_user/?$u29219?admin_form=True`, user.user)
const results = await verifiedGet(`get_user/?$u302932?admin_form=True`, user.user)
```

is this possible to do so?

I created a sandbox for a better understanding

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-star-fegy7

Comment: You need to normal for each and append string

Comment: hi Shubham, could you show me how?

Comment: I have updated your sandbox check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chatterjee-lijnw?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

I would take your unique id array and use Array.Join() to combine them with commas.

```js
// Map the ids, and filter unique
const uniqueIds = value
  .map((person) => person.value)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

// Join the Ids and separate them with commas
const commaSeparatedIds = uniqueIds.join[','];

// Don't forget to make them safe for a URL
// You may be able to skip this if you are certain 
// your string is safe
const uriSafeIds = encodeURIComponent(commaSeparatedIds);

// Finally, interpolate into your string literal template
// I wasn't sure if the extra $ in your code was intended
// so I left it in.
const url = `get_user/hello?$${uriSafeIds}?admin_form=True`;

const results = await verifiedGet(url, user.user);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `const id = user.map((person) => person);`, we are looping through the 'user' array and for each iteration, we are just returning the element in that iteration. The '[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)' function will return an Array of what will be returned in each iteration. So, basically, we are re-creating the `user` array in `id`.

```js
const user = ["u29219", "u302932"];

// 'user' array is re-created here
const id = user.map((person) => person);

console.log("from", id);

const results = `get_user/?${id}admin_form=True`;
```

If your intention was to form the `results` string with each element in the array, this would be a way to do it using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
user.forEach((person) => {
    const results = `get_user/?${person}$admin_form=True`;
    // remaining logic
});
```

[Code-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lehmann-tgko4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: thanks @sreek is there a way tot access the results outside of the forEach/map function?

Comment: @stack5flow, you can declare an Array (say `allResults`) before the loop, and, in the loop, you can push the `results` string into the `allResults` by doing `allResults.push(results)`. So, you can access all of them outside the loop. But, If the operations are to be made on each `results` string, I suggest to move that logic inside the loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can make the array unique, then concat or join to get the expected output.

```
const user = ["u29219", "u302932", "u302932"];
const uniqueItems = [...new Set(user)];
console.log("current uniqueItems", uniqueItems);
let results = "";
uniqueItems.forEach((person) => {
  results = results.concat(`get_user/?${person}$admin_form=True `);
});
console.log("current output", results);
```